# (How) Can I reuse this PVC 4-way

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pvc, irrigation

Some contractors broke my irrigation system and I'm in the process of repairing it. One of the connections to a PVC 4-way junction had a piece of schedule-40 PVC broken off inside it. As luck would have it, this is the inlet from the source.

As near as I can tell, there is no way to reuse the junction and it must be cut out of all the other splices and reconnected in those branches as well. Am I wrong, can it be reused? And if so, how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: unless that octogon part unscrews I suspect that you are right,

Answer (score 1):

You can try filing the broken piece out with a Dremel tool with a sanding drum attachment but I've had little luck doing that. You're better off just cutting out the junction and installing a new one with three repair sleeves. Good luck.

Comment: While you have this dug out, install a plastic irrigation valve box around this instead of backfilling with dirt again.